# Clear the listview in android

Tags: android

I have Appnum which extends listactivity. In oncreate() I got whatever I want (these are actually phone numbers). Problem starts when I come back again my numbers are shown twice. again if I come back third time these numbers are shown thrice. I can't find any "thing" to remove this fault.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // setContentView(R.layout.list_layout);
        try {
            mnListAdapter.clear();

        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
```

Comment: show your full java activity code

Comment: Add the list only for the first time.or else clear list data and add the new data

Comment: you can clear your adapter and again set on list view to clear that.....

Comment: thnks for the replying soon . i have solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

try to use `ListView.invalidate()` or `ListView.notifyDataSetChanged()`